# Javascript simply multiplying user input and displaying it

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to convert my code to work client side and not with a mongo collection. However, I am having trouble making the user input display correctly without using a DB.

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById("timeframe");
    var options = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
      if (options == "weekly"){
        var salary = event.target.salary.value;
        var budget = {salary:  salary * 52};
        budget
        people.insert(budget);
        return false;
      };
```

This is the code that worked with my mongo collection.

If he user selected weekly from the drop down menu, and entered a number, it would multiply the number by 52 and display the total.

Now, I am trying to make it work the same way but without storing the data in a DB, just storing it as a session variable.

i replaced the line:  `people.insert(budget);`

With:  `Session.set("salary", event.target.salary.value);`

But this just displays exactly what the user input, for example , if the user inputs 10, it will display 10.

I am sure I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, with `people.insert(budget);` you're using the variable `budget` (with value `{salary:  salary * 52}`), but when it comes to session, you are using the variable that's yet to be multiplied by 52 (`event.target.salary.value`).

You have some options:
1- Change the code to `Session.set("salary", event.target.salary.value * 52);`

2- Use the following: `Session.set("salary", budget.salary);`

**3** - Change `var budget = {salary:  salary * 52};` to `var budget = salary * 52;` so you can use it like this: `Session.set("salary", budget);`

I'd pick the 3rd.

Comment: oh sorry, yeah I tried Session.set("salary", budget)  but that displayed "Object Object" as a result..

Comment: What happens if you use `Session.set("salary", event.target.salary.value * 52);` instead?

Comment: thats it, thank you, I knew it was something small like that. Cheers